# Model trained using LSTM is predicting only same value for all

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a dataset with 4000 rows and two columns. The first column contains some sentences and the second column contains some numbers for it.
There are some 4000 sentences and they are categorized by some 100 different numbers. For example:

```
Sentences                                         Codes

Google headquarters is in California              87390
Steve Jobs was a great man                        70214
Steve Jobs has done great technology innovations  70214
Google pixel is a very nice phone                 87390
Microsoft is another great giant in technology    67012
Bill Gates founded Microsoft                      67012
```

Similarly, there are a total of 4000 rows containing these sentences and these rows are classified with 100 such codes

I have tried the below code but when I am predicting, it is predicting one same value for all. IN othr words y_pred is giving an array of same values.

May I know where is the code going wrong

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

xl = pd.ExcelFile("dataSet.xlsx")
df = xl.parse('Sheet1') 

#df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)# shuffling the dataframe


df = df.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)# shuffling the dataframe
X = df.iloc[:, 0].values
Y = df.iloc[:, 1].values

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
import pickle 

count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X = count_vect.fit_transform(X)

tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X)

X = X.toarray()

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_Y = LabelEncoder()
Y = labelencoder_Y.fit_transform(Y)
y = Y.reshape(-1, 1)  # Because Y has only one column

onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
Y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y).toarray()


from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

inputDataLength = len(X_test[0])
outputDataLength = len(Y[0])

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.layers import Dropout

# fitting the model
embedding_vector_length = 100
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(outputDataLength,embedding_vector_length, input_length=inputDataLength))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(outputDataLength))
model.add(Dense(outputDataLength, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
print(model.summary())
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=20)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
invorg = model.inverse_transform(y_test)
y_test = labelencoder_Y.inverse_transform(invorg)
inv = onehotencoder.inverse_transform(y_pred)
y_pred = labelencoder_Y.inverse_transform(inv)
```

Comment: So you have 100 classes. Then you must use `categorical_crossentropy` for loss. Also after predicting you must take `argmax` of the prediction

Answer (score 2):

You are using `binary_crossentropy` eventhough you have `100` classes. Which is not the right thing to do. You have to use `categorical_crossentropy` for this task.

Compile your model like this,

`model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])`

Also, you are predicting with the model and converting to class labels like this,

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
inv = onehotencoder.inverse_transform(y_pred)
y_pred = labelencoder_Y.inverse_transform(inv)
```

Since your model is activated with softmax inorder to get the class label, you have to find the `argmax` of the predictions.

For example, if the prediction was `[0.2, 0.3, 0.0005, 0.99]` you have to take argmax, which will give you output `3`. The class that have high probability.

So you have to modify the prediction code like this,

```
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
y_pred = labelencoder_Y.inverse_transform(y_pred)

invorg = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)
invorg = labelencoder_Y.inverse_transform(invorg)
```

Now you will have the actual class labels in `invorg` and predicted class labels at `y_pred`

Comment: I guess you can use `binary_crossentropy` with `categorical_accuracy`

Comment: Yes you can. Main problem in the code in question was in prediction.

Comment: What about the one hot encoding which I am using?
y = Y.reshape(-1, 1) 
onehotencoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto')
Y = onehotencoder.fit_transform(y).toarray()

Comment: the constant output which I am getting
array(['67012', '67012', '67012', ..., '67012', '67012', '67012'],
      dtype='<U6')

Comment: what do you mean by output.? Does `model.predict()` give you that result.?

Comment: y_pred = labelencoder_Y.inverse_transform(y_pred) gives me that result

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on it? Also, can we use LSTM for text classification? more specifically on the kind of dataset I mentioned?

Comment: LSTM can be used for text classification. Like any deep learning method LSTM models works well if there is abundant data. Since your dataset is so small for an LSTM and you got 100 classes, you will find difficulty in making your model converge

Comment: Sorry, I did not get a notification, we had a small part of the actual dataset. In actual, we have 15000 rows, 2 columns, 100 classes